# How big are "twin" beds in Japan?

Tags: japan, hotels, terminology

It's been my experience that "twin" sized beds in Japanese hotels are quite a bit bigger than what we would call "twin" here in the US. How wide/long are they exactly?

Comment: I was very confused by this question, until I found on Wiki: "What is referred to as a "single bed" in many parts of the world is known in U.S. terminology as a "twin bed". In some countries, a "twin bed" may also be used to describe one of two single beds in the same room."

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find this [chart of bed sizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bed_size#Table_of_sizes) to be just what you need.

- North America: 39in × 75in (0.99 m × 1.91 m)
- Japan: 38in × 77in (0.97 m × 1.95 m)

Which would seem to indicate you're perhaps mistaken in your experience, unless they have a different custom size that you've been experiencing.

Comment: Technically 38"x77" is 2,926 square inches, exactly one square inch more than 39"x75", which is 2,925 square inches.