# How big is a "semi-double" bed in Japan?

Tags: japan, accommodation, terminology, sleeping

I'm looking at accommodation for an upcoming trip to Japan.

A room I'm looking at quotes a "semi-double bed", a size I've never heard of. I found [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/how-big-are-twin-beds-in-japan) asking about "twin beds", but the [Wikipedia page on bed sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bed_size#Table_of_sizes) it links to doesn't mention semi-doubles.

How big is a semi-double in Japan, and is it suitable for two people to sleep comfortably?

Comment: Typing "semi-double bed" into Bing netted me [120 cm wide](http://www.fodors.com/community/asia/bed-size-in-japan.cfm) where a "normal" double bed it 140 cm, and a single is 90 cm.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**A Semi-double bed is around 120 to 140cm (47 to 55in), depending on the hotel.**

As for it being suitable for two people, that depends on how close you are:

I shared a semi-double bed at Mystays Asakusa-Bashi with a friend. If it hadn't been my long time friend, I would have been very uncomfortable as you WILL end up touching/brushing the other person while sleeping, even if you don't move much.

Here's an image of such a bed in Asakusa-Bashi. The size here is 120cm.

[image]

If it's your significant other, you should be fine.

Comment: Using a 1.20 bed, I say that even with your loved one, if you do not prefer to sleep cuddling, it is just big enough or not big enough if you are big yourselves.

Answer (score 2):

Semi-double is 120cm width, while double is 140cm, single is 100cm, and semi-single, which you rarely see is 80cm.

I don't know what @JSLavertu took the figure from, but usually the size of semi-double is 120cm, not 120cm to 140cm.

Although some people might sleep together, I don't recommend it. Especially if both are men, it is highly uncomfortable. Semi-double is created for those who want more space than single, and thus is suitable for only one person.

---

These pages are written in Japanese, but from a bed speciality store, which states that "semi-double is a size of 120cm width:

- http://www.bedroom.co.jp/contents/howto2/size/
- http://bed-recommended.hachultra.jp/size/

Comment: In the past, 120 beds were considered big enough for two adults or three kids, 5 if two were having their heads at the other end of the bed. Norms have changed and I have to agree that a 120 bed is perfect for a single person but loads of people will still be able to use it with two adults. And yes, I know what I am talking about, it was the size of my grand parents bed, my bed and the bed used by a friend and her husband.

Comment: @pnuts  Yes but it is written in Japanese; anyway I'll add it when I go back.

Comment: @pnuts I don't think government regulates it and there is no reason they should do. Though I shall not say it as official however, I edited it. But I haven't seen 130cm; it is all around 120cm, maybe +/- 1 or 2 cm margin might be accepted, though.

Comment: @pnuts When did I criticize? I just mentioned it, though I disagree if he considers it up to 140cm. And please don't delete the comments so readily as others don't get what happens here.

Comment: I got that figure from my own personal experience of sleeping in semi-double rooms for the two times I went to Japan in the last year. The semi-double beds ranged from 120 to 140cm. Hope that helps.